Outlook Android add space between image in emails
I've done a huge email for my client but Outlook android still add space between row when there is an image. Desktop version are fine but I can't have a good display on mobile. Do you know what's happenging here ?
You can this my email here : http://email.smithevents.fr/prefikar/rr2024/RR.html
I added this in 
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
<o:AllowPNG/>
<o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->

and this in my 
align="center" valign="middle" style="margin: 0; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;"

